# Grub won't recognize Windows on a difference drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I've been looking for solutions to this problem everywhere on here, but none of theme seem to fix my problem.

I have a Dell XPS 15 with two drives: a 1TB Hard drive, and a 32GB SSD. Dell was supposed to put Windows on the SSD, but since they didn't I put Ubuntu on it. Currently I have the boot order in BIOS set to my SSD, so it automatically boots to Ubuntu, however if I want to boot to Windows, I have to spam F12 until I get the bios boot menu, and choose windows from there. I'd prefer to use Grub, so I can just have the menu pop up automatically.

Grub works and lets me boot to Ubuntu, however it doesn't recognize Windows. I tried tons of solutions, but none of them had fixed anything. The windows boot partition is on sdb1, so I tried to add a manual grub entry for (hd1,1), and it doesn't seem to work. I also tried using blkid to put the uuid in of the drive, but it doenst recognize that either. I'm a little stuck, and if someone could help me, that'd be awesome. I'm not sure what information I should post, but here's some stuff:

Running sudo fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 96FB9AA3-4F2B-4031-8AE9-4A66B995BCAC

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1        2048    1026047    1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/sdb2     1026048    1288191     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb3     1288192 1929156607 1927868416 919.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb4  1929156608 1930078207     921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb5  1930078208 1953519615   23441408  11.2G Windows recovery environment
```

Running blkid /dev/sdb1:

```
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="ESP" UUID="CCFB-1926" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="4b301afe-77b0-419a-9307-2c809b6584bf"
```

/etc/grub.d/40_custom:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry 'Windows 10' {
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd1,1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 4b301afe-77b0-419a-9307-2c809b6584bf
    chainloader +1
}
```

If you need any other information, please let me know. I appreciate any help, thanks!

**Edit:
I should also mention boot-repair doesn't work, and I just did a clean install of Ubuntu, so I don't think grub needs to be reinstalled**

Comment: How it boots is how it installs. Keeping that in mind, have you installed Ubuntu in EFI mode? You should have because the factory installed Windows is in EFI mode, as usual. Otherwise, you can only dual-boot the way you've been doing, from the UEFI menu.

Comment: That might be my issue... I followed my friend's instructions when I first installed ubuntu and it said legacy boot I think. Is there any reason I wouldn't be able to boot ubuntu to UEFI mode? I honestly don't know the difference at all, but I remember in the XPS instructions for installing ubuntu it had something about swapping boot modes

Comment: Again, how it boots is how it installs. If the settings were UEFI+Legacy (or CSM) at the time you installed Ubuntu then you would have seen the USB flash drive twice in the boot options menu, one with *UEFI: ...* and other without it. More info here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Wow, I did not know this at all. That's crazy helpful, thanks a lot! I will reinstall ubuntu in UEFI and report back. Thanks a lot!